# Jquery Tooltip not working with bootstrap js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an angular directive for jquery tooltip.

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("tooltip", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{ 
            title: "@",
            template: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element){
            $(element).tooltip({
                title: scope.title,
                tooltipClass: scope.template
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[Demo-1 is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/5qjae1k2/) and working.(not referenced bootstrap.js yet)

But if I use bootstrap.js on my project, it is not working.

[Demo-2 is here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/5qjae1k2/3/) and not working. (I referenced bootstrap.js)

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/5qjae1k2/4/)... looks like Shashank's answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bootstrap.js` is also having a `tooltip` feature named with `tooltip` function. So it is overriding the `tooltip` function of the jQuery UI `tooltip` function.

If you have to use both jQuery UI and Bootstrap plugins but wants tooltip of jQuery UI, just include the `bootstrap.min.js` before the `jquery-ui.min.js`.

Comment: This answer is correct. If we have two functions with the same name (in js) the one which is at the end gets called... See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/5qjae1k2/4/) for the above answer

Comment: Here is the forked version of your 2nd example which is working http://jsfiddle.net/8h7aa4ok/ after swapping the positions of `bootstrap.js` and `jquery-ui.js`

Comment: I have a small issue, tooltip arrows not appearing.

Comment: Looks like jQuery UI by default does not show a tooltip arrow but you can customize it as given in there docs https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heads up, Demo-2 is working: `added position relative` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qjae1k2/6/)

Just in-case you want to use it: [tooltip options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options)